# I just wanted to say: Thank you!

Tags: discussion

I don't have a question at the moment. I had a question about whether "bear" was correct when used as a verb as in  bear with me" I found the answer and much more on this site. I wanted to write a "Thank you comment" saying how useful this site is, but I was not able to submit one. I hope I am not wasting space and people's time, but thank you very much for this very useful site.
Kind regards,
Steve Iversen

Comment: Look guys! It works. The system works!

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Was the comment at least 15 characters?

Comment: @WilliamD.Edwards At least 50 rep is required to comment anywhere (as opposed to commenting on one's own posts).

Comment: @AndrewLeach I know.

Comment: No problem!  http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/146671/when-should-no-problem-replace-youre-welcome-as-a-response-to-thank-you

Comment: And the internet's small heart grew three sizes that day.

Comment: I tried to find the original question about "bear" and could not.  I think it would be useful to have a link to that question so that users could see what kind of reception of a new user makes "the system work".  That is,  was the question a good question, or was no one feeling burned out that day?

Comment: [I don't think Ricky was convinced](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7299/i-really-dont-see-why-ignorant-idiots-should-be-allowed-to-edit-my-posts)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to **thank** this community and its members, is by contributing back, and **helping** making it what it was for you, for *others*!

**How**?

- **upvote** what you find **useful**, so **others** can find it too.
- downvote what you find **unclear**, so the OP's are pushed to **edit** and **clarify** their post. Take it easy on this one!
- **share** your knowledge, either by creating **Q & A** styled posts, or by answering others.

  - **Research** before asking a **new** question, and show what you **found & tried**.

> **On behalf of SE: You are very welcome! Keep up the good work!**